# How do I see if any programs are emulating keys

Tags: c#, keyboard, keyevent, anti-cheat

I've made a game where the task is to press spacebar 100 times which is mutiplayer, People are starting to use simple applications which spam the key "space" and I'm wondering if there is a way to only listen for user input or detect programs which are emulating key events.

I've not tested one of these programs but my program listens for KeyUp event.

Just tested: They can emulate key presses

Comment: I don't think so, because the emulator simply sends the emulated Key-Event to the OS, which handles the event and sends it to your program, since you can't reprogram the OS there is imho no way.

Comment: No, I think your better of looking into patches, such as look at the consistancy of when the space button is hit, if same every time - will be programised. Or if 100 has been pressed in like 2 seconds, it will be programised, so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best bet is to see if the time between all the spaces are exactly the same.  A human would likely have some kind of variance.  Make a judgement over some period of time.

Comment: What kind of value would I be best at trying? I'll time the different between keyup and keydown and if it's within a certain value more then 5 times it will kick them.

Comment: I would measure the time between key downs, or key ups, or both.  Compare the time between 100 key downs.  If they are all the same, it is likely being done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

One big gotcha:  All they need is to solder an oscillator to a donor keyboard and then it's not even visible inside any of the computer's processes.  Sounds like a lot of work but you'd be surprised how hard people will work to cheat.  Detect this with timing checks as mentioned above.  Not a whole lot of people know how to make spread-spectrum clocks.